# How can I group table columns in a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
+------+------+------------+
|Child |Parent|ParentType  |
+------+------+------------+
|Mike  |Ellie | 1          |
+------+------+------------+
|Mike  |Jack  | 2          |
+------+------+------------+
|Sam   |Holly | 1          |
+------+------+------------+
|Sam   |Brad  | 2          |
+------+------+------------+
```

Type 1 is Mom and type 2 is Dad

I want to write a SELECT statement which has this result:

```
+------+------+------+
|Child |Mom   | Dad  |
+------+------+------+
|Mike  |Ellie | Jack |
+------+------+------+
|Sam   |Holly | Brad |
+------+------+------+
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select child,
       max(case when parenttype = 1 then parent end) as mom,
       max(case when parenttype = 2 then parent end) as dad
from t
group by child;
```

Of course, these days, children can have two Mom's or two Dad's or whatever, so I recommend `string_agg()`:

```
select child,
       string_agg(case when parenttype = 1 then parent end, ',') as mom,
       string_agg(case when parenttype = 2 then parent end, ',') as dad
from t
group by child;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but i have many columns in select statement.

is there any way do this without group by?

or how can use group by with many many columns?

Comment: @Busra put your requirements in the question, so people solve your actual problem, not a dumbed-down version.

Comment: I'm sorry, my query was so confused so i wanted to explain my problem basicly. Thanks for your answers

Comment: @Busra . . . This answers the question you asked here.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question with an appropriate level of detail.